# latex conditional include input files

Tags: input, multiple-files, versions

I have the following latex file structure (for a good reason) and I would like to use preamble in both `main.tex` and `other_main.tex`

```
|-main.tex
|-subsections
     |-preamble.tex
     |-input1.tex
|-other_main
     |-other_main.tex
```

However, the issue is that preamble inputs `input1.tex`. For `main.tex` to be compiled, preamble.tex needs to use

```
\input{subsections/input1}
```

While for `other_main.tex` to be compiles, `preamble.tex` needs to use

```
\input{../subsections/input1}
```

---

**What I've tried**: using `versions` package with the following files:

preamble.tex

```
\begin{main}
    \input{subsections/input1}
\end{main}

\begin{other}
    \input{../subsections/input1}
\end{other}
```

input1.tex

```
\newcommand{\hi}{hi}
```

main.tex

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{versions}
\includeversion{main}
\excludeversion{other}

\input{preamble}

\begin{document}
    \hi
\end{document}
```

But I'm getting `! Undefined control sequence. \hi` error.

---

I could make a copy of `preamble.tex` with the different input location, but that is not desirable as the contents of preamble may change over time.

Any idea how to tackle this problem? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the paths are relative to the working directory of latex, not to the document so one possibility is to process the second document from the same working directory but use

```
pdflatex other-main/other-main.tex
```

Then you need the same path for both.

Alternatively (and better as it is more portable) is to just use
`\input{preamble}`  (or better rename the file to `preamble.sty` and use `\usepackage{preamble}`.

Then arrange that `preamble.tex` is in the input path of both documents.

You could do this either by setting the TEXINPUTS environment variable to

```
/path/to/main//:
```

where `main` is the directory containing `main.tex` and `//` means recursively search any subdirectory and the trailing `:` means search all the standard places.

Or simply put preamble.tex in your local texmf treee so it is found anywhere, typically in  `~/texmf/tex/latex`

Comment: Thanks @DavidCarlisle, would I have to move input1.tex along with preamble if I were to turn `preamble` into a `sty`?

Comment: @Tim if I understand the question no. `\usepackage{foo}` if you ignore package option setting, is just syntactic sugar for `\input{foo.sty}`

Comment: thanks so much @DavidCarlisle! I think I got it. Seems like setting `TEXINPUTS=/path/to/main//;` worked for me on windows. Turns out that automatically includes `input1.tex` into path so that `\input{input1}` works for both `main` and `other_main`.